# What does photon-limited imaging mean?

Tags: photons, noise, sensor

The following link is about Photon-Limited Imaging,
https://engineering.purdue.edu/ChanGroup/project_QIS.html.
Is there any definition of Photon-Limited Imaging. 
From the paper **Photon-Limited Object Detection using Non-local Feature Matching and Knowledge Distillation**, it mentions that *Photon-limited imaging refers to image acquisition under a condition where the number of measured photons is very low. The fundamental limit is attributed to the Poisson process of the photon arrivals. This randomness is present even if the sensor is perfect – no read noise, no dark current, and has a uniform pixel response.*

However, photon transfer curve shows that read noise dominates the total noise at the start.[image]
The above figure is from the link https://www.edn.com/digital-camera-design-part-5-basic-noise-considerations-for-cmos-image-sensors/?_ga=2.182323620.2008979889.1647429375-317472058.1647429364.
Is the read noise smaller than the photon shot noise in low light with technological advance in the CMOS image sensor?

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, it means that the Poisson distribution of incoming photons (or any particle stream) when there are very few total photons present is the primary source of image noise/blur.  As you probably know, the Poisson $SNR = Const*\sqrt(N)$ , or equivalently the StdDev  $\sigma = Const*\sqrt(N))$ .  This hold not only for the arrival rate, as is done when computing electrical current shot noise, but for the spatial distribution over the image.
When the photon count gets larger, the spot size, or, more accurately, the spot centroid,  is limited either by the diffraction limit (Airy Disk for a circular lens aperture) or by the geometric spot size if the optical system is of relatively low quality.

Comment: Thanks. Is photon shot noise larger than read noise under such situation? Does photon transfer curve still hold when the signal is very weak?

Comment: @JoggingSong The quoted text specifically says this is the situation with zero read noise. If read noise is greater than photon noise then that term dominates.  If by "photon transfer curve" you mean Quantum Efficiency, i.e. electrons per photon, then that remain constant up to very large photon flux levels.

Comment: The PTC curve comprises four distrinct regimes. The first regime is read noise limited and the signal is weak in terms of the curve. When the illumination is continuously increasing, photon shot noise will become dominant and it will not be a low light situation. I can't imagine the photon shot noise is larger than read noise under low light. The quoted text maybe mean that photon shot noise is attributed to the principle of light and can't be elliminated.

Comment: @JoggingSong well, expand your imagination :-) .  You could look at the performance specs for , e.g.  the JWST cameras.   Astronomical cameras can reach read noise of a few electrons over a multi-minute-long exposure.

Comment: The read noise should include the noise resulted from dark current. What about read noise of CMOS image sensors in mobile phones?